the chef's reply to 御馳走様でした
What would a chef say to a patron that is thanking him and saying "御馳走様でした"?

They would normally reply with ありがとうございました.
eg

客：（会計後、店を出る際）「ごちそうさまでした～。」
店主とスタッフ：「ありがとうございました。またお越しくださいませ。」


A chef will likely say something among lines of お粗末さん.

お店でそれは聞いたことがないのですが。。。「ごっそさん！」に祖母が「はい、お粗末さまでした。」って言ってましたけど。
